# Facing very weird bug in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am facing very weird bug in iOS whenever I am trying to make a debug build it's not running packager loading very old code same happens with the release scheme but when I am running the packager manually with npm start than latest code started running but the apis giving 401 error with axios and fetch, In log it's sending proper headers, tested headers in postman and it is working fine too. Don't know what to do.

Comment: Start from product>clean build folder or delete DerivedData

Comment: have you updated the info.plist with arbitrary load?

Comment: tried this and pod deintegrate too

Comment: not sure about arbitrary load

Comment: Share screenshots/log of error you are facing.

Comment: i tried but wasn't able to find any error in log app is running fine its just running very old code